# Details in the process of constructing a std::thread object

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, language-lawyer, stdthread

I'm interested in (and confused about) the details of constructing a `std::thread` object. According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), both the thread function and all arguments are value-copied to some thread-accessible storage, and then invoke.

**1) What exactly is this thread-accessible storage?** Is it semantically equivalent to some kind of thread-local storage, and the variables are destructed after the thread function returned?

**2) What is the value-category of the arguments when passed to the thread function?** The description on cppreference suggests that they are passed as l-values (they are given names anyway). My tests on GCC and clang seem to suggest the opposite, i.e., r-values. Specifically, the following code does not compile:

```
void f(int& a) {
  std::cout << ++a << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::thread t(&f, 1);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles if we change `f` to

```
void f(int&& a) {
  std::cout << ++a << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::thread t(&f, 1);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

So, what does the standard say about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) This "thread-accessible storage" bit of text is not represented directly in the standard. The standard simply says that the function is invoked with arguments obtained by `decay_copy`.

2) If you study `decay_copy` closely, you will find that it returns *by value* (because its return type is `std::decay` of something). So the function `f` is called with rvalue arguments (prvalue arguments, in fact).

If you want to pass lvalues (references), you can use `std::ref` and `std::cref` to wrap them.

The exact quote, C++11 30.3.1.2/4:

> *Effects:* Constructs an object of type `thread`. The new thread of execution executes *`INVOKE(DECAY_COPY ( std::forward<F>(f)), DECAY_COPY (std::forward<Args>(args))...)`* with the calls to
>   *`DECAY_COPY`* being evaluated in the constructing thread. Any return value from this invocation is
>   ignored. [ *Note:* This implies that any exceptions not thrown from the invocation of the copy of `f`
>   will be thrown in the constructing thread, not the new thread. *—end note* ] If the invocation of
>   *`INVOKE(DECAY_COPY ( std::forward<F>(f)), DECAY_COPY (std::forward<Args>(args))...)`* terminates
>   with an uncaught exception, `std::terminate` shall be called.

*`DECAY_COPY`* is defined in 30.2.6/1:

> In several places in this Clause the operation *`DECAY_COPY(x)`* is used. All such uses mean call the function
>   `decay_copy(x)` and use the result, where `decay_copy` is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> template <class T> typename decay<T>::type decay_copy(T&& v)
> { return std::forward<T>(v); }
> ```

*`INVOKE`* is defined in 20.8.2 pretty much in the same way as cppreference describes the invocation in the link you've provided.

Comment: So, the new thread is executing `INVOKE(DECAY_COPY ( std::forward<F>(f)), DECAY_COPY (std::forward<Args>(args))...)` except that `DECAY_COPY` has already been done in the constructing thread. I would infer that the temporaries returned by `DECAY_COPY` are destructed after `INVOKE` has returned and the destruction is performed by the constructed thread.

Comment: The wording about storage appears to have been inspired by the boost.thread docs  ("func is copied into storage managed internally by the thread library...")