# Accessing a moved std::string in a new thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, move, stdthread

Consider the case below

The name string is moved as an argument to the thread.

```
 void start(std::string&& name) {
        t = std::thread{&ThreadRunner::run, this, std::forward<std::string>(name)};
    }
```

The thread's run function also takes a rvalue reference.

```
 void run(std::string&& name) {
        const auto errnum = pthread_setname_np(t.native_handle(), name.c_str());
        if (errnum != 0) {
            std::cout << "ERROR " << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

The thread is created via the start function as below:

```
  ThreadRunner r;
  r.start(std::string("somename"));
```

The question is. Could it be possible that the std::string accessed in the function`run` via pthread_setname_np can be junk because the temporary went out of scope when it's scope ended?

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nDeB5b7XxiFcavFp) 
In the above demo, after `call` ended, is it guranteed that the `somename` string is valid in the function `run`?

Edit:
[Demo with constructors/destructors](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Lf4DeY6Xv2sSvaNH)
The std::string in the question is now replaced with a `Wrap` to print the constructors involved.

The result is: (second field is the address of the object, third is the thread id)

```
Constructed 0x7ffc395e0ef0 140605000369984
Move Constructed 0x7ffc395e0e60 140605000369984
Move Constructed 0x177a0a0 140605000369984
Destroyed 0x7ffc395e0e60 140605000369984
Destroyed 0x7ffc395e0ef0 140605000369984
Call ended

somename
Destroyed 0x177a0a0 140604983461632
```

The last object, is destroyed after `run` ends. Does it still refer to a temporary. I think not.

[A more clean example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FPPmFFujds5c9oTe)

Edit:
After the comments, the question boils down to

> "After the original call to void start(std::string&& name); has
>   returned and after the constructor of std::thread has ended, where is
>   the string that void run(std::string&& name); is working on? "

The latest demo code seems to show that the object `Wrap` being referenced by `run` gets destroyed after `run` exits.

Comment: Instead of abusing `std::forward` for a job that it wasn't designed to provide, please use `std::move`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Details in the process of constructing a std::thread object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693630/details-in-the-process-of-constructing-a-stdthread-object)

The accepted answer in the above post clarifies the situation here.
The function `run` takes a reference to a temporary which is destroyed **after** the completion of the `run` function.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no dangling reference**, because the constructor arguments of `std::thread` are copied/moved into some structure by the client thread. The newly created thread will then run on the copied/moved objects in this structure.

In your specific case, the `std::string` object is indeed moved into the described structure. That's the `std::string` object `run()` is working on. It will be properly destroyed when the thread finishes its execution.